# Scroll bar at the bottom of page in HTML

Tags: html, css

im having a problem with this code:

```
<style>
#tabimg{
}
#tabpara{
position:relative;
left:310px;
top:-310px;
}
</style>

<h1>CLICK ON THIS HEADING</h1>
<div id="hideme" height="400">
  <div id="tabimg">
    <img src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" width="300" height="300">
  </div>
  <div id="tabpara" width="300" height="300" >
    <p>Paragraph Text</p>
  </div>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#hideme").hide();
    $("h1").click(function(){
                $("#hideme").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm getting a scroll bar at the bottom of the page and i don't know why?
I'm quite new to HTML+JavaScript so apologies if its a simple mistake,
Thanks :)

Comment: Show a working example of the issue.

Comment: What are you working on? Also, it may depend on your viewport

Comment: Im coding using notepad++ and opening directly in google chrome,

Comment: If the question was answered, don't edit solved into the title, just click the green tick nex to the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the width parameter to your css and remove the direct width="300" parameter :

```
#tabpara
{
 position:relative;
 left:310px; 
 top:-310px;
 width:300px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's worked perfect, why is this method different to the way i was doing it before?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting the scroll bar is this CSS rule:

```
#tabpara {
    left: 310px;
}
```

The paragraph will fit perfectly if you don't push it with the `left`. Also, inline styles like `width="300"` is something that you should not rely on. Use CSS to change the width of the element:

```
#tabpara {
    left: 310px;
    width: 300px;
    top: -310px;
}
```

Comment: Okay i wont use the inline method, i just needed the text to the right of the image which is what the left: command was for